# How to get access token to publish action using JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the following code to get access token via javascript sdk

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        FB.init({ 
            appId: 'insert your appID value here', 
            cookie: true, 
            xfbml: true, 
            status: true });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                alert('#AccessToken').val(response.authResponse.accessToken);
            } else {
                // do something...maybe show a login prompt
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Now i want to use the access token from above code and use it below for publishing action, i have tried different things but none of them worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function read()
{
FB.api('/me/news.reads' +
'?article=Yoursite.com/test.html&access_token=access token from above','post',
function(response) {
var msg = 'Error occured';
if (!response || response.error) {
if (response.error) {
msg += "\n\nType: "+response.error.type+"\n\nMessage: "+response.error.message;
}
alert(msg);
}
else {
alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
}
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: You’re not showing us the actual code of the things you say you’ve tried … Anyway, there should be no need to actively set the access token – once you’ve received one, the SDKs are normally able to handle it on their own.

Comment: I have tried access_token=+FB._session.access_token